# Regex match in google app engine webapp WSGIApplication

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

Hi  A rather simple question:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
('/result', Result),
('/result/', Result),
```

The only difference is the trailing '/'.

Can I merge the two url mapping into one?

Answer (score 2):

For SEO reasons, it is usually better to choose one URL to handle, and redirect the other to the chosen one. Otherwise search engines will see duplicate content. For example something like this:

```
class RedirectHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect("/result/", True)

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([ 
    ('/result', RedirectHandler), 
    ('/result/', Result), 
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`'/result/?'`

The question mark makes the preceding character optional.

Answer (score -1):

by default the google app engine will recognize /result/ same as /result so you can just go with

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
('/result', Result),
```

you can as well make regular expressions for links such as

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
('/block/([0-9]+)/permissions', Result),
```

Comment: I will try that. But `/result/` and `/result` are not the same. I am using `/result/` and it wont work when people type `/result`.

Comment: just try the /result for start

Comment: This answer is wrong. App Engine will not perform any magic on trailing slashes (or lack thereof).

Comment: @NickJohnson strange thing that i actually use app engine and i didn't have issues with is, but whatever